# Returning more than one node as a string using the string() function in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, coldfusion-10

I'm currently delving into the wonderful world of XML.. After having a bit of a tinker with an XML set up there is one thing that has me stumped which I noticed when trying to build a navigation. I'll set up an example below to demonstrate my issue.

```
<cfxml variable="myXML">
    <navigation>
        <navItem>
            <name>Mens</name>
        </navItem>

        <navItem>
            <name>Womens</name>
        </navItem>
    </navigation>
</cfxml>

<cfset navList = arrayToList(xmlSearch(xmlParse(myXML),
    "string(//navItem/name/text()), "^")>

<cfloop list="#navList#" delimiter="^" index="nav">
    <cfoutput>
        #nav#
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

My aim is to have this:

```
Mens
Womens
```

This may begin to make sense to some now. I'm trying to return the name value as a string of **EACH** `<navItem>` within the XML tree. Of course the error i'm being thrown does make sense, however now i'm stuck as to how I go about returning multiple nodes values as strings.

The error I recieve states:

```
Unable to process the result of the XMLSearch for A sequence
of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument
of string() (text("Mens"), text("Womens")).
```

Followed by:

```
ColdFusion is unable to process the result of the XPath search.
You may have an undefined variable in the xpath expression.
```

Can anyone point in me along the right lines of what im after?

Answer (score 1):

I would simply try

```
<cfset navList = arrayToList(xmlSearch(xmlParse(myXML), "//navItem/name"), "^")>
```

If that does not work then

```
<cfset navList = arrayToList(xmlSearch(xmlParse(myXML), "//navItem/name/string()"), "^")>
```